# If statement is not working when inserting data using PHP PDO Prepared statements

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

This is my code:

```
<?php

$salary = 0;

try {


    // prepare sql and bind parameters
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO TABLE (firstname, salary) 
    VALUES (:firstname, :salary)");
    $stmt->bindParam(':firstname', $firstname);
    $stmt->bindParam(':salary', $salary);

    // insert a row

    $firstname = "John";
  if ( $respond["salary"] != 0)
    $salary= $response["salary"];
    $stmt->execute();

    echo "New records created successfully";
    }

?>
```

This is just the required code. In the full code, I retrieve 5-10 JSON files using a whileloop.

I get `$response["salary"] from a JSON file`, but if the salary in JSON  file is empty, i put the value as 0. So it does not store the value of previous JSON files.

But what happens here is:

If the salary in JSON file is empty, then i give $salary variable `0` value.

So, according to the IF Statement, no value of salary must be stored, because salary = 0. But it still stores 0 in the database. How to fix it?

Comment: you have a typo. it should be `if($response["salary"])`

Comment: your IF stores the salery into the bound variable, but the execute statement is executed always (see manual: http://php.net/manual/de/control-structures.if.php)

Comment: It does not matter @FMashiro

Comment: @nabuchodonossor false, it doesn't, it just doesn't compare the type. Just the value.

Comment: What does `$respond` actually do?

Comment: It sends a value. Like $respond["salary"] sometimes send "32434", "3243", "234244", "67546"..But sometimes, it send "" (no value)

Comment: okay so im a bit puzzled.. above it says `$response` but now you're saying `$respond`. Which one is it?

Comment: @Josh `it does not matter` how does your typo "not matter"? xD

Comment: Most PHP problems are typo related, I find sometimes my errors are solely due to typing `$helo` rather than `$hello` (example btw :P )

Comment: @FMashiro `false, it doesn't, it just doesn't compare the type. Just the value.` What are you even talking about? :D He talked about the missing curly braces at the if. Thus $stmt->execute is called always because he is using a oneliner-if.

Comment: @Xatenev I was talking about the way he phrased it. I thought that he meant that `!=` assigned the value to the variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My assumption is that you're calling the wrong query within your `IF` statement.

Here's my take on it:

```
$salary  = 0;

$stmt = $this->conn->prepare("INSERT INTO `table` (`firstname`,`salary`) VALUES (?,?)");


if (!empty($response['salary']) && $response['salary'] != 0)
{
    $salary = $response['salary'];
    $stmt->execute([$firstname, $salary]);

    echo 'New record created successfully';
} else {
    echo 'error!';
}
```

My only other suggestion would be to `var_dump($respond)` and then `var_dump($response)` and see which one you should actually be calling...

Comment: But in your code  $stmt->execute will get only executed, if their is value of salary, and where to write $firstname value? 

So, i need to use multiple  $stmt->execute???

Comment: No it wouldnt? It states, if salary doesnt = 0 then execute the firstname and the salary insert query, else, if it does = 0 then throw `error`